# How to replace consecutive occurances of a specific character?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make the following string replacements:

```
Something!!!!!!!! something! something!` => `Something! something! something!
Something!!!!..... something! something!` => `Something!. something! something!
```

How can I specify a character to do this in Ruby or Rails?

Comment: This is not specific to Ruby on Rails

Comment: @theTinMan Why did you add the ruby-on-rails tag back ?

Comment: Because the OP specifically said "Rails". This isn't really a Rails question per se, but that was the OPs interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby's `String.squeeze` is your friend:

```
'Something!!!!..... something! something!'.squeeze('!.')
=> "Something!. something! something!"
```

Comment: Didn't know it could take many characters. Better than regexes anyway

Comment: "beer".squeeze('!.') => "beer"

Comment: @Jacob you have to specify the characters you want to squeeze

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know squeeze could take arguments too.

Comment: I use it regularly to normalize spaces in documents before parsing them.

Answer (score 1):

```
irb(main):011:0> s = "Something!!!!..... something! something!"
=> "Something!!!!..... something! something!"
irb(main):012:0> s.gsub(/(.)\1+/, '\1')
=> "Something!. something! something!"
```

becomes

```
irb(main):001:0> s = "sweet"
=> "sweet"
irb(main):002:0> c = "."
=> "."
irb(main):003:0> s.gsub(Regexp.new("#{Regexp.escape(c)}{2,}"), c)
=> "sweet"
irb(main):004:0> s = "Something!!!!..... something! something!"
=> "Something!!!!..... something! something!"
irb(main):005:0> s.gsub(Regexp.new("#{Regexp.escape(c)}{2,}"), c)
=> "Something!!!!. something! something!"
```

Comment: only problem is with something like `sweet` which will get converted to `swet`. Hence a way need to specify character.

Comment: Indeed. I didn't think about that

Answer (score 0):

A specific character should be fairly straight forward:

```
def remove_extra_occurances(string, character)
  string.gsub(/#{Regexp.escape(character)}{2,}/, character)
end
```

To have it work for any character would require a really clever regex. Have to admit I'm not sure if a regex would suffice, or if a loop structure would be required.

Comment: That doesn't work with `.` as it replaces the whole string :)

Comment: Hint: [`Regexp.escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-c-escape).

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to escape '.', as well as any other characters that are meaningful in a regex. For '.' specifically, this should work: `string.gsub(/\.+/, '.')`

Comment: To replace multiple occurrences of all characters: `str = str.gsub /(.)\1+/, '\1'`